# How to make title sortable with two different tables whose data coming from same model in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have a view showing two tables which data is coming from same model but based on different column status I divided in 2 tables. Problem is, when I click on top table's column name heading for sorting, it also sort the bottom tables. I'm wanting the bottom table data won't sort when I click on top table column heading title. If any one have a good solution, would highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you sorting this table?  Are you using javascript or Paginator?  What version of CakePHP are you using...etc etc etc.  Please include detail about your question.

Comment: not possible since the two tables reference exactly the same data, except if you duplicate the data in two models

Comment: I'm using Paginator CakePHP version 2, I have a Model name Address which have 2 types of addresses, for example is_preferred = 0 & is_preferred = 1, I have divided the 2 tables in the view based on this condition from controller. Is it possible to differ the sorting function of these 2 tables ?

Comment: @NikosM. - "not possible" is almost always incorrect.

Comment: @Dave, ok sometimes, if sorting is done in cakephp, and the same data are referenced it is not possible (at least this way). i'm explaining here and not using maxims out of context

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on your setup, but you're going to have to do some custom code.

For example, don't allow Cake to sort for you.  See what the links look like when created by Cake, then write your own, and include an additional variable `&table=1` or something.

Based on the sort variable and the table variable, build your pagination options for each including the correct sort you want for each group **separately**.

---

Another option (depending on how large your data sets are) is to use [javascript datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: The sorting function is already done with Cake Default Paginator & there are 20+ columns, so I'm looking if there is any option to add extra parameter when call $this->Paginator->sort() function without doing any custom code. I've searched but no luck I found.

Comment: Ok I solved it by doing passing custom parameter and sorting with find query rather than using Paginator.